# FOSCommentBundle symfony 3 critical error

Tags: php, symfony, foscommentbundle

im installing foscomment bundle in my project and im following the documentation provided with this bundle in git hub

this is the link

[documentation git hub](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle)

and when i want to update my database schema this exception appears to me and i couldnt figure out what is the problem

```
 [2017-02-11 17:06:57] php.CRITICAL: Fatal Compile Error: Declaration of Group\GroupBundle\Entity\Comment::setThread() must be compatible with FOS\CommentBundle\Model\CommentInterface::setThread(FOS\CommentBundle\Model\ThreadInterface $thread) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 0): Compile Error: Declaration of Group\\GroupBundle\\Entity\\Comment::setThread() must be compatible with FOS\\CommentBundle\\Model\\CommentInterface::setThread(FOS\\CommentBundle\\Model\\ThreadInterface $thread) at C:\\wamp\\www\\E-Randopi\\src\\Group\\GroupBundle\\Entity\\Comment.php:18)"} 


[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                      
Compile Error: Declaration of Group\GroupBundle\Entity\Comment::setThread()  
 must be compatible with FOS\CommentBundle\Model\CommentInterface::setThrea  
 d(FOS\CommentBundle\Model\ThreadInterface $thread)                           


doctrine:schema:update [--complete] [--dump-sql] [-f|--force] [--em [EM]] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

this is my error output

[image: error]

this is my comment entity

```
<?php

 namespace Group\GroupBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\CommentBundle\Entity\Comment as BaseComment;


/**
   * Commentaire
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="commentaire")
   * @ORM\Entity
   * @ORM\ChangeTrackingPolicy("DEFERRED_EXPLICIT")

 */
 class Comment extends BaseComment
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * Thread of this comment
 *
 * @var Thread
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group\GroupBundle\Entity\Thread")
 */
protected $thread;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_createur", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $idCreateur;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_publication", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $idPublication;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 */
private $photo;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_commentaire", type="date", nullable=false)
 */
private $dateCommentaire;

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return Thread
 */
public function getThread()
{
    return $this->thread;
}

/**
 * @param Thread $thread
 */
public function setThread($thread)
{
    $this->thread = $thread;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * @param string $description
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getIdCreateur()
{
    return $this->idCreateur;
}

/**
 * @param int $idCreateur
 */
public function setIdCreateur($idCreateur)
{
    $this->idCreateur = $idCreateur;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getIdPublication()
{
    return $this->idPublication;
}

/**
 * @param int $idPublication
 */
public function setIdPublication($idPublication)
{
    $this->idPublication = $idPublication;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getPhoto()
{
    return $this->photo;
}

/**
 * @param string $photo
 */
public function setPhoto($photo)
{
    $this->photo = $photo;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDateCommentaire()
{
    return $this->dateCommentaire;
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime $dateCommentaire
 */
public function setDateCommentaire($dateCommentaire)
{
    $this->dateCommentaire = $dateCommentaire;
}


}
```

Comment: Thnks man the error is gone  but the comment input is not showing in my view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setThread() method must be declared according to `CommentInterface::setThread()` of the FOSCommentBundle which is:

```
/**
 * @param ThreadInterface $thread
 */
public function setThread(ThreadInterface $thread);
```

and your `Comment::setThread()` declaration is:

```
/**
 * @param Thread $thread
 */
public function setThread($thread)
{
    $this->thread = $thread;
}
```